# how to remove a subset from a column within square brackets in r

Tags: r, rselenium

I've a column with has multiple strings in square brackets something like this `[asdf] [ffgg][ asdf asdf asdf] sdfsgsfbsfg` and I've to extract `[asdf asdf asdf]` it may have only one string like `[asdf]` or two. Please help

Comment: @Andrew Gustar, do you have any idea for this.

Comment: I assume your string is `"[asdf] [ffgg][asdf asdf asdf] sdfsgsfbsfg"` and want to extract `"[asdf asdf asdf]"`  Regarding the second part `it may have only one string like `"[asdf]"`, it is not clear why you don't want to extract `"[asdf]"` or `"[ffgg]"` from the string you posted

Comment: I need the  [asdf asdf asdf] for my future coding, whereas the rest are of no use now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\[(\\w+\\s+){2,}\\w+\\]")    
#[1] "[asdf asdf asdf]"
```

Or may be

```
str_extract(str1, "\\[(\\w+\\s+)\\1+[^]]+\\]")
#[1] "[asdf asdf asdf]"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "[asdf] [ffgg][asdf asdf asdf] sdfsgsfbsfg"
```

Comment: THis is returning NA NA NA NA NA.... actually I have a column with 25 rows with this kind of data [asdf] [ffgg] [ asdf asdf asdf] sdfsgsfbsfg and I need to extract [ asdf asdf asdf] and this has a one common thing in all 25 rows that it starts with 1 like [11asdf]

Comment: @kishore if you look at the data I used, it is not returning NA NA NA...

Comment: You are right, here it is giving me the correct output.
Let me simplify it.
[bear] [Mert2] [117CrtRu9] asdfsdafs: [CRsdfasd]
[bear] [Mert2] [118C8rty9] asdfsdafs: [CRsdfasd]
[bear] [Mert2] [119C8rth9] asdfsdafs: [CRsdfasd]
similary for 25 rows and I need the data in [117CrtRu9]  that is 3rd bracket of all the rows in different column2

Comment: Alternatively can this str_extract(str1, "\\[(\\w+\\s+){2,}\\w+\\]")   be applied to a column in my table with multiple rows?

Comment: @kishore  Yes, you can do that `str_extract(df1$yourcolumn , pattern)`

Comment: thanks, can  you tell me how you'll break down this in patterns I think I didn' get the concept behind the creating a pattern [kkj2] [1] [113MY17HH 115MW5KZH 112QYCMGY ] doing something I want the matter in [113MY17HH 115MW5KZH 112QYCMGY ] to be taken out from my column list