# Extract last substring between square brackets

Tags: r, regex, rselenium

I've a column of data from which I need to extract a alphnumeric string/factor example

```
Column x
[ghjg6] [fdg5] [113gi4lki] great work 
[xzswedc: acf] [xzt8] [111eerrh5] 
[asd2] [1] [113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh ] get out
```

I want to get the data in the square brackets `[113gi4lki]`, `[111eerrh5]` and `[113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh]` in a separate column. Please advise.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the code you have for this specific problem and explain where you're stuck

Comment: I tried library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "\\[(\\w+\\s+){2,}\\w+\\]")    
my initial code opens a link and reads an html table. From there I took a column which has the data as shown above and I want to extract the one shown above for further calculations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093818/how-to-remove-a-subset-from-a-column-within-square-brackets-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
Column.x <- c(
"[ghjg6] [fdg5] [113gi4lki] great work",
"[xzswedc: acf] [xzt8] [111eerrh5]",
"[asd2] [1] [113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh ] get out")
y <- gsub(".*\\[", "[", Column.x)
gsub("\\].*", "]", y)
```

result:

```
> gsub("\\].*", "]", y)
[1] "[113gi4lki]"                      "[111eerrh5]"                      "[113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh ]"
```

If you want you can put both steps together:

```
gsub("\\].*", "]", gsub(".*\\[", "[", Column.x))
```

Comment: thanks this works great, can I do this to a data frame directly whose length is 25 and how

Comment: I got it worked on the column as well thank, it is just missing one or two rows that is pulling wrong string.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text inside the last set of `[...]` brackets, you may use a `sub` with the following pattern:

```
".*\\[([^][]+)].*"
```

The pattern matches:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars greedily, as many as possible, up to the *last* occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\\[` - a literal `[` (must be escaped outside of the bracket expression)
- `([^][]+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `\1`) matching 1 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a literal `]` (no need escaping it outside of a bracket expression
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

[R online demo](http://ideone.com/ORz5P5):

```
x <- c("[ghjg6] [fdg5] [113gi4lki] great work", "[xzswedc: acf] [xzt8] [111eerrh5]", "[asd2] [1] [113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh ] get out", "Some text with no brackets")
df <- data.frame(x)
df$x = sub(".*\\[([^][]+)].*", "\\1", df$x)
df
```

Output:

```
                               x
1                      113gi4lki
2                      111eerrh5
3 113vu17hg 115er5lgr 112cgnmbh 
4     Some text with no brackets
```

If you want to remove the entries with no `[...]` (like the last one in my test set), use

```
df$x = sub(".*\\[([^][]+)].*|.*", "\\1", df$x)
```

See [another online R demo](http://ideone.com/YMKOBb).

Comment: Stribizew thank you for the above script. I came up with something else like `str_extract(df$Subject,"[:punct:]+([:digit:]+[:alpha:]+)+[:punct:]")-> df$x2` which is providing 90% of the correct data however your line of code if giving me the rest 10%.

If I use both that is df$x2 as column 1 and output from your script as column 2 I get some garbage data in column 2. 

I've two things to do now:
1. use both the codes and merge which should discard the garbage data and give me 100% needed data
2. try to look similar syntax for your code in my script format.
`

Comment: The `str_extract(df$Subject,"[:punct:]+([:digit:]+[:alpha:]+)+[:p‌​unct:]")` is wrong. You need to use POSIX character classes inside bracket expressions. Also, I guess by using `[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]+` you want to match alphanumeric? Then use `[[:alnum:]]` and turn the `[[:punct:]]` part into lookaheads (or - if you just have `[...]`, use the `\\[` and `]`). Try `str_extract(df$Subject,"(?<=\\[)[[:alnum:]]+(?=])")` - but it won't return the *last* occurrences of [texts].

Comment: @kishore: Please explain the rules again. Revise your question and edit accordingly as right now, it is not clear any longer what the requirements are.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, Can we chat please, I would be able to explain clearly?

Comment: @kishore Try to add more messages here.

Comment: @kishore: Maybe `"(?<=\\[)[^]\\[]+(?=])(?!.*\\[[^]\\[]*])"` will work best for you with `str_extract`?

Comment: Or use `library(stringi)` and then `stri_extract_last(df$x,regex="(?<=\\[)[^]\\[]+(?=])") -> df$x3`

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, ok, so I need to extract anything which starts with "11" and has a length of 9 eg 113gi4lki. Just now I tried `str_extract(df$Subject,"([:digit:]+[:alpha:]+[:alnum:]+)")-> df$x1` and got 98% accuracy but I'm missing where there are many character like this [113gi4lki 114gi4lki 115gi4lki].This type of data is being pulled from your query however some garbage value is also being pulled like [ghjg6], [xzswedc: acf], [1] (this is just for eg). I want to have this 113gi4lki 114gi4lki 115gi4lki kind data only which might be separated by '/ ' like 113gi4lki / 114gi4lki /115gi4lki

Comment: Yes, I see. So the position in the string may be *any*?

Comment: Yes the string can be anywhere in the subject and in the any format either separated by space, comma or / and may not be [ ](a little rare). it is sure to start with 113,115,116 or 11 to be more precise with length 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146502/discussion-between-wiktor-stribizew-and-kishore).

Comment: You need [`(?<=\[)[^\w\]\[]*11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\w\]\[]+11[[:alnum:]]{7})*[^\w\]\[]*(?=])`](https://regex101.com/r/YNnzBN/1). If `[` and `]` can be missing, just remove the lookarounds: [`\b11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\w\]\[]+11[[:alnum:]]{7})*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/YNnzBN/3). Double the backslashes in R.

Comment: @kishore: (Note that SO inserts rubbish into the comment text, and the first pattern above won't work if you copy paste it from the comment above, copy from the regex101.com!)

Comment: @kishore: Please let me know if it works, and I will update the answer then.

Comment: `stri_extract_last(df$Subject,regex="(?<=\[)[^\w\]\[]*11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\w\]\[]+11[[:alnum:]]{‌​7})*[^\w\]\[]*(?=])") -> df$x3`

gives the below error

Error: '\[' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<=\["

`stri_extract_last(df$Subject,regex="\b11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\w\]\[]+11[[:alnum:]]{7})*\b") -> df$x3`

gives the error as

Error: '\w' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\b11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\w"

Comment: @kishore: I told to **double the backslashes in R**.

Comment: `regex="\\b11[[:alnum:]]{7}(?:[^\‌​\w\\]\\[]+11[[:alnum:]]‌​{7})*\\b"` - to define a backslash in an R string literal, you need to use 2 backslashes.